How do I prevent Vite from using "import" in bundled JS files and instead use the imported code directly in the file that's importing it?
I'm trying to make a Chrome extension in Typescript and React, and I'm using Vite to bundle it to three javascript files, background.js, contentScript.js and popup.js, which will be stored in the 'dist' folder.
input: {
    popup: resolve(__dirname, 'src/popup/Popup.tsx'),
    background: resolve(__dirname, 'src/background/background.ts'),
    contentScript: resolve(__dirname,'src/contentScript/contentScript.ts'),
}

However, I have a file named chromeStorage.ts that's used in both the content script and the popup. Vite seems to optimize it (I'm assuming) by creating chromeStorage.js in the 'dist' folder and then importing it using "import from './chromeStorage.js'" in both bundles, contentScript.js and popup.js, instead of duplicating the code in both files. However, what I actually want is for it to use whatever it's importing directly in both files, rather than importing it.
I tried using optimizeDeps exclude in the vite config file, but it doesn't seem to have much to do with my problem.
I also tried changing format in the vite config file, but to no avail.
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            format: 'system'
        }
    }
}


I suggest updating the title of your question to more accurately reflect that you want "...for it to use whatever it's importing directly in both files, rather than importing it." (That is, you intentionally want the file contents to be duplicated.) I'm afraid I don't know how to do that. It almost sounds like you want two different build targets.

Sounds like How do I completely disable chunking in Vite and Rollup?

Turning off chunking seems to work, thank you! Specifically, having multiple config files, each one for one input file and then setting "output.inlineDynamicImports: true" in all of them.
